# Import CSV with dates and use for calculate NETWORKDAYS in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to create a list from import a CSV and use this list for count in networkdays.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Show us some code so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pandas (you need to first install it using pip)

```py
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv('file.csv')
```

or if you don't want to install pandas you can do this

```py
import csv
f = open('file.csv')
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
```

Comment: Tks Pranav. How can i use this import for calculate holidays? In my job we cant install the pips Holidays and others things. We have tried in many ways to calculate business days by discounting holidays.